# Looking to remove a set of characters from a .txt file

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, shell

I am looking for a way to remove the content from one `.txt` file based on the other.

For example, I have a `file.txt` with 2000 character that are random and not sorted.  I have another file `importantfile.txt` with 2016 characters that have the same characters that `file.txt` has as well as 16 other characters randomly placed in.

Is there any way to remove the characters in `file.txt` from `importantfile.txt` to find the 16 character string.

Some errors I found that in the diff command is that It would print the whole string because It was considered one word `diff file.txt importantfile.txt` would return `w881lYoi8042aKGfwj7EjenViinsmbmnWIHJMZ2T9L40KiLr4x485TM3gKmc1Ig8n6VVW82iqjxypCp19sXIMisX4HIkp54lVohqKSuLjjuns91GiEwtTsvN0zhn6c9GZC2GqUKLsy9v1SvSKvdSPBmIJtNoSwr65BBGqLQ1LdHg93kfZoCq5NPxkaYjIyppzYaczGlwZBrsKyjbTEI5B1aWuw6g9xBZ1viussKRP5C5Pq5yO14P8xBDHGugo93mwf7rsjNehNuxDSAt` shortened for obvious reasons, but the start of both strings would be `w881l.....` I also tried java script, using the `importantfile.replace("file","");` code but it returns the whole string as well. Anything helps, thanks

Comment: say this is part of the original (file.txt) w881lYoi8042aKGfwj7EjenViinsmbmnWIHJMZ2T9L40KiLr4x485TM3gKmc1Ig8n6VVW82iqjxypCp19sXIMisX4HIkp54lVohqKSuLjjuns91GiEwtTsvN0zhn6c9GZC2GqUKLsy9v1SvSKvdSPBmIJtNoSwr65BBGqLQ1LdHg93kfZoCq5NPxkaYjIyppzYaczGlwZBrsKyjbTEI5B1aWuw6g9xBZ1viussKRP5C5PqDHGugo93 And lets say this is part of the changed text (importantfile.txt)    w881lYoi8042aKGfwj7EjenViinsmbmnWIHJMZ2T9L40KiLr4x485TM3gKmc1Ig8n6VVW82iqjxypCp19sXIMisX4HIkp54lVohqKSuLjjuns91GiEwtTsvN0zhn6c9GZC2GqUKLsy9v1SvSKvdSPBmIJtNoSwr65BBGqLQ1LdHg93kfZoCdq5NPxkaYjIyppzYaczGlwZBrsKyjbTEI5B1aWuw6g9xBZ1viussKRP5C5Pq5

Comment: @GarrettWeber, Welcome to SO, please edit your post with samples, comments are NOT meant for adding samples. Kindly use CODE TAGS `{}` button to wrap them in it as per rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctry, how about:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{str1 = $0; next} {str2 = $0}
END {
    for (i = j = 1; j <= length(str2); ) {
        if (substr(str1, i, 1) == substr(str2, j, 1)) {
            incr = 1
        } else {
            incr = 0
            printf "%s", substr(str2, j, 1)
        }
        i+=incr; j++
    }
    print ""
}' file.txt importantfile.txt
```

Output:

```
d5
```